# I quote/ I am quoting

Tags: present-tense, present-progressive

This is the last paragraph of a book review:

"To conclude, I quote the concluding paragraph from the..."

Is this correct English? Why is it "I quote"? Can "I am quoting" be used insteand?

Comment: *I quote* is correct. But I would have said something like *Here is the concluding paragraph...*.  And I would not have said *To conclude...concluding...*.  One almost never needs to say *To conclude*.

Answer (score 3):

"I quote" is correct because it also maintains parallelism with "to conclude".

if it were "concluding the review" then "I am quoting" would be appropriate.

informally, both are okay.

Answer (score 0):

I tentatively offer (ha! I used a simple tense myself without even thinking about it) a possible reason for this puzzling preference for simple tenses in situations such as the asker asks about: it might be a stylistic throw-back to the time before English developed the continuous tense. This was were still unusual in 1600 (there are very few continuous tenses in the Authorised Version of the Bible, published in 1611, although it has a sprinkling of them). Modern authors writing essays almost always use the simple present tense in phrases such as "I posit ...", "I submit ...", "I offer a possible solution ...", "I conclude ...", "I quote ..." etc., etc.

Another reason might be that the continuous tense generally implies an action that is interrupted, or that is about to be interrupted, by another action. ("Don't interrupt him, he's working"; "The man was crossing the street when suddenly...") Interruptions are probably rarely relevant to the writing of intellectual and philosphical thoughts.